# What's my GitHub appliance's REST API endpoint?

Tags: github-api

I want to use Groovy, HttpBuilder and REST API to access our company's onsidte GitHub appliance. 
The GitHub developer's site: https://developer.github.com/v3/, shows this URL: https://api.github.com. So if my company's GitHub URL is: http://github.mycompany.com, what is my REST API endpoint URL? e.g. if I want to list all users, what's the correct URL?

When I access this URL: https://github.mycompany.com/api/v3, it gives me an error:

github.mycompany.com refused to connect.
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Answer (score 25, accepted):

According to "[API Enterprise 2.5](https://developer.github.com/v3/enterprise/)":

> All API endpoints—except [Management Console](https://developer.github.com/v3/enterprise/management_console/) API endpoints—are prefixed with the following URL:

```
https://hostname/api/v3/
```

But you need to authenticate:

> ### Authentication

> Your Enterprise installation's API endpoints accept [the same authentication methods](http://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication) as the GitHub.com API. Specifically, you can authenticate yourself with **[OAuth tokens](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/)** (which can be created using the [Authorizations API)](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth_authorizations/#create-a-new-authorization)  or [**basic authentication**](https://developer.github.com/v3/#basic-authentication).

> Every Enterprise API endpoint is only accessible to GitHub Enterprise site administrators, with the exception of the [Management Console](https://developer.github.com/v3/enterprise/management_console/) API, which is only accessible via the [Management Console password](https://help.github.com/enterprise/admin/articles/accessing-the-management-console/).

Comment: Downvoted for this `http(s)`, always default to a secure solution

Comment: @JBirdVegas agreed. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Downvote became an upvote, thank you sir.

Answer (score 13):

TLTR; These are the endpoints

```
+----+------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|    |                Enterprise                |             GitHub             |
+----+------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
| v3 | https://[YOUR_HOST]/api/v3               | https://api.github.com         |
| v4 | https://[YOUR_HOST]/api/graphql          | https://api.github.com/graphql |
+----+------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
```

### Examples

Here you have some examples in case you want to try them. You'll need to create an [ACCESS_TOKEN](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/)

**Enterprise**

```
curl -H "Authorization: bearer [ACCESS_TOKEN]" https://[YOUR_HOST]/api/v3/organizations
curl -H "authorization: bearer [ACCESS_TOKEN]" https://[YOUR_HOST]/api/graphql -d "{\"query\": \"query { viewer { login } }\"}"
```

**GitHub**

```
curl -H "Authorization: bearer [ACCESS_TOKEN]" https://api.github.com/organizations
curl -H "authorization: bearer [ACCESS_TOKEN]" https://api.github.com/graphql -d "{\"query\": \"query { viewer { login } }\"}"
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are not using https, it's "http://github.mycompany.com/api/v3/".

Answer (score 2):

You're getting that message because the request is not authenticated.

First you have to figure out what kind of auth your server accepts and then incorporate that into the header or the (query string) of your request.

For example, this is how I get a list (using the header approach) of organizations I can access:

```
`url -k -H "Authorization: token xxxxxx...xxx" \ https://git.acme.com/api/v3/organizations`
```

Note that xxxxx...xxx is a place holder for a personal access token I created with read-only access to my repos. The docs refer to this as OAUTH_TOKEN. You can opt for inserting the token as a query string. In **neither** case do you have to enter a user name because the server figures that out from the token.

Answer (score 0):

if you need https://github.com/google/shaka-player it would be
https://api.github.com/repos/google/shaka-player

more info at https://api.github.com/

```
  "current_user_url": "https://api.github.com/user",

  "current_user_authorizations_html_url": https://github.com/settings/connections/applications{/client_id}",

  "authorizations_url": "https://api.github.com/authorizations",

  "code_search_url": "https://api.github.com/search/code?q={query}{&page,per_page,sort,order}",

  "commit_search_url": "https://api.github.com/search/commits?q={query}{&page,per_page,sort,order}",

  "emails_url": "https://api.github.com/user/emails",

  "emojis_url": "https://api.github.com/emojis",

  "events_url": "https://api.github.com/events",

  "feeds_url": "https://api.github.com/feeds",

  "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/user/followers",

  "following_url": "https://api.github.com/user/following{/target}",

  "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/gists{/gist_id}",

  "hub_url": "https://api.github.com/hub",

  "issue_search_url": "https://api.github.com/search/issues?q={query}{&page,per_page,sort,order}",

  "issues_url": "https://api.github.com/issues",

  "keys_url": "https://api.github.com/user/keys",

  "label_search_url": "https://api.github.com/search/labels?q={query}&repository_id={repository_id}{&page,per_page}",

  "notifications_url": "https://api.github.com/notifications",

  "organization_url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/{org}",

  "organization_repositories_url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/{org}/repos{?type,page,per_page,sort}",

  "organization_teams_url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/{org}/teams",

  "public_gists_url": "https://api.github.com/gists/public",

  "rate_limit_url": "https://api.github.com/rate_limit",

  "repository_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}",

  "repository_search_url": "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q={query}{&page,per_page,sort,order}",

  "current_user_repositories_url": "https://api.github.com/user/repos{?type,page,per_page,sort}",

  "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/user/starred{/owner}{/repo}",

  "starred_gists_url": "https://api.github.com/gists/starred",

  "topic_search_url": "https://api.github.com/search/topics?q={query}{&page,per_page}",

  "user_url": "https://api.github.com/users/{user}",

  "user_organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/user/orgs",

  "user_repositories_url": "https://api.github.com/users/{user}/repos{?type,page,per_page,sort}",

  "user_search_url": "https://api.github.com/search/users?q={query}{&page,per_page,sort,order}"
```